# Passing multiple parameters and a javascript function in input button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass several parameters and a javascript function in a button.

I have to pass a parameter `vToggle` and the value is `ON` and a javascript function `Ingredient()`.

I tried like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick=
    "Ingredient(); |
    javascript: document.getElementById('_set').value='vToggle \'ON\'';
    Submit();"
/>
```

Comment: The input statement that i tried. 
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="Ingredient(); | javascript: document.getElementById('_set').value='vToggle \'ON\'';  Submit();" />

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWS8n/1/).

JavaScript

```
function buttonClick() {
    Ingredient();
    document.getElementById('_set').value='vToggle \'ON\'';
    Submit();
};​
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="javascript: buttonClick();">Click me</button>​
```

But be aware that you load the script that creates the function before the button loads.
If you don't want to load your function before the button is loaded you need to delay the binding to the click event. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TVSqS/4/) for a demo.

HTML

```
<button id="ingredientButton">Click me</button>​
```

JavaScript

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {

    document.getElementById("ingredientButton").onclick = function() {
        Ingredient();
        document.getElementById('_set').value='vToggle \'ON\'';
        Submit();
    };

}​
```

Comment: @user1397157 You're welcome! Please mark this as the 'approved answer'? Thanks!

Comment: @user1397157 Happy with my answer? Would you like to approve my answer?